# Compile static shared library with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, linux

I want to create shared library (.so) that is statically linked, so it will not have dependencies on other libraries and can work on any version of linux.

My **example.h**

```
#ifndef example_h__
#define example_h__

#include <stdint.h>

extern void example_1(void);

#endif  // example_h__
```

My **example.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void example_1(void) {
    puts("Hello, I'm a shared library");
}
```

My **Makefile**:

```
all :
    gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic example.c
    gcc -shared -Wl,-Bstatic -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -L/opt/musl/lib -I/opt/musl/include -o libexample.so example.o
    readelf -d libexample.so
```

I already compiled musl lib from source with -fPIC option and still getting this error:

```
# make
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic example.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-Bstatic -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -L/opt/musl/lib -I/opt/musl/include -o libexample.so example.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /opt/musl/lib/libc.a(__stdout_write.lo): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against protected symbol `__stdio_write' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to solve it?

Comment: `.so` are just not for static linkage but are dynamic libraries. For static linkage an `.a` archive produced with `ar` is sufficient.  Also, for C code you should not need any libraries that have `c++` in their name.

Comment: So how to create `.so` library that contains all it's dependencies?

Comment: Just add `-static` option to your compilation
and don't forget to remove `-shared`
in this case you will have `.a` file - it's your static library

Comment: Do you think it's possible to load `.a` files dynamically? e.g. with FFI